# why in linux work and in win not?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, glew, devil

I'm using glew, glut, opengl and devil lib.
In Ubu 13.10 with c++ this line compile but in Visual Studio in Win not!
Why?
std::string path is a parameter passed into the function.
This is the code:

```
//Load image
ILboolean success = ilLoadImage( path.c_str() );
```

This is the error:

```
cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char *' to 'const wchar_t *'
```

Comment: Probably whatever library provides `ilLoadImage` is compiled "for Unicode" in Windows, which means it expects a "wide string" as a parameter.

Comment: Because Microsoft C++ uses wide chars by default. You should convert your string to a "wide" string, by using one of the Win32 API functions or some function in glew/glut.

Comment: Actually, converting from narrow to wide strings is not a good idea, on Windows you should probably work with wide strings from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your default setting in Visual Studio is to compile with a wide character set (`UNICODE`).  You can either turn off that flag (compile for ANSI) which will utilize a single byte character set (`std::string`), or change your existing code to utilize a wide character set (`std::wstring`).

Comment: Please don't call Windows wide characters "Unicode". While similar in many aspects, they're not. In Windows a wide character is always 16 bits wide. In Unicode a single codepoint ("character") may consist of several bytes of varying length.

Comment: @datenwolf To turn on the wide character set, you have to set the `UNICODE` preprocessor flag (which is on by default in the newer versions of VS).  To turn it off, you have to remove the same flag.  You may not like the semantics, but you'd have to take that up with Microsoft.